# Why using the lo index to solve the Binary Search problem is not same as using the hi index?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search

I am solving the below problem using Binary Search :-

```
Suppose an array of length n sorted in ascending order is rotated between 1 and n times. For example, the array nums = [0,1,2,4,5,6,7] might become:

[4,5,6,7,0,1,2] if it was rotated 4 times.
[0,1,2,4,5,6,7] if it was rotated 7 times.
Notice that rotating an array [a[0], a[1], a[2], ..., a[n-1]] 1 time results in the array [a[n-1], a[0], a[1], a[2], ..., a[n-2]].

Given the sorted rotated array nums of unique elements, return the minimum element of this array.

You must write an algorithm that runs in O(log n) time.
```

Obviously this last line gives away that I should be using Binary Search to solve the problem.

First consider the below examples :-

```
Example 1:

Input: nums = [3,4,5,1,2]
Output: 1
Explanation: The original array was [1,2,3,4,5] rotated 3 times.
Example 2:

Input: nums = [4,5,6,7,0,1,2]
Output: 0
Explanation: The original array was [0,1,2,4,5,6,7] and it was rotated 4 times.
Example 3:

Input: nums = [11,13,15,17]
Output: 11
Explanation: The original array was [11,13,15,17] and it was rotated 4 times.
```

And here are the constraints of the problem :-

```
Constraints:

n == nums.length
1 <= n <= 5000
-5000 <= nums[i] <= 5000
All the integers of nums are unique.
nums is sorted and rotated between 1 and n times.
```

And here is my first solution :-

```
class Solution {
    public int findMin(int[] nums) {
        int lo = 0, hi = nums.length - 1, mid = -1;
        if(nums[lo] <= nums[hi]) return nums[lo]; // Doing this to handle single elements array and the unrotated array without getting into the loop. Even the array will contain distinct element for a single element the first and last element will be the same hence the equality.
        
        while(lo <= hi){
            mid = (lo + hi) >>> 1; // Finding the mid.
            if(mid > 0 && nums[mid] < nums[mid - 1]) return nums[mid];
            if(nums[mid] < nums[hi]) hi = mid - 1; // Using the hi index to ascertain the correct half
            else lo = mid + 1;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Now my question is that if you try lo index, instead of using the hi index, then you just can't do it without adding an extra condition.
I mean the following code will not work.

```
class Solution {
    public int findMin(int[] nums) {
        int lo = 0, hi = nums.length - 1, mid = -1;
        if(nums[lo] <= nums[hi]) return nums[lo];

        while(lo <= hi){
            mid = (lo + hi) >>> 1;
            if(mid > 0 && nums[mid] < nums[mid - 1]) return nums[mid];
            if(nums[mid] < nums[lo]) hi = mid - 1; //the smallest element is to the left of mid
            else lo = mid + 1; // Otherwise, the smallest element is to the right of mid
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

As can be verified with the following test case :-

```
[4,5,6,7,0,1,2]
```

In the above code, I have just changed the condition to use the lo index to figure out which half the minimum element is located.

To make
Here is that extra condition code :-

```
class Solution {
    public int findMin(int[] nums) {
        int lo = 0, hi = nums.length - 1, mid = -1;
        if(nums[lo] <= nums[hi]) return nums[lo];

        while(lo <= hi){
            mid = (lo + hi) >>> 1;
            if(mid - 1 >= 0 && nums[mid] < nums[mid - 1]) return nums[mid];
            else if( mid + 1 <= hi && nums[mid] > nums[mid + 1]) return nums[mid + 1]; // this second condition is extra and was not needed previously.

            else if(nums[mid] < nums[lo]) hi = mid - 1; // Notice that nums[lo] being used
            else lo = mid + 1;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I want to understand why the second code is not working without adding the extra condition. Please help me unravel this ?
The test case where the second solution will fail if I remove the second condition is this :-

```
[4,5,6,7,0,1,2]
```

it should give the value 0, but it's not if the second condition is being removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Various situation encountered while doing the search]

As shown, above there could be various situations encountered while doing the search, the minimum element could be in the right half of the array, as shown in the Picture 1. If we compare the mid value with the 0th index value, then mid is greater and hence we have to move to the right to get the minimum value under the assumption that rotation is there. But it could be that the array is sorted but not at all rotated or it is rotated the same as the number of elements in the array. In that case our choice of moving to the right by setting lo = mid + 1 is plain wrong. Hence choosing the firstVal, which is at index 0, as comparison point, in this particular application of Binary Search is wrong.

Let's check the case of selecting the last value of the array as the comparison point.

If the minimum is in the right half, then mid is greater than the end value, so we move lo to the mid + 1.

If the mid is less than the end value, i.e value at the last index, then we move hi to mid, as that very value at mid could be the minimum value, so we are not going mid - 1.

Now let's see if the array is not at all rotated or similar situations, then the minimum is at the 0th index, so if we go the mid index value, we get a value which is less than the end value (value at the last index), so it makes sense that we move to the left of the mid. Remember we had taken the same decision of moving to the left when the minimum was in the first half and there also the mid was less than the end value.
So moving to the left is correct in all aspects of rotated or unrotated array.
Hence we should solve the above problem with the end value, for an easy straightforward solution.

But it's nobody's case that this problem can not be solved with comparing the mid index with the value at the 0th index value.
It can be done, only thing the solution will have to handle the ambiguity resulting from the below shown two kind of cases :-

[image: The ambiguous situations encountered while considering the first index value]

This can be solved by adding an extra condition, if the mid value ia greater than the value at lo, then there are two situations either the array is rotated and the minimum is on the right half, as shown in the first picture above.
Or
the array is not rotated or is rotated so much that all the elements have come back to their original positions.

We can tackle these two situations by adding an extra condition in the code :-

```
class Solution {
    public int findMin(int[] nums){
        int lo = 0, hi = nums.length - 1, mid = -1, firstVal = nums[lo];
        while(lo < hi){
            mid = (lo + hi) >>> 1;
            if(nums[mid] >= firstVal){// if mid val is greater or equal to the first val, then the min is either on the left if the array is unrotated, or in the right half. If unrotated then the first value will be always less than or equal to the end value. Otherwise the first value will be always greater than the end value
                if(nums[lo] <= nums[hi]){ // this one checks if the array is sorted
                    hi = mid;
                }else { // if not sorted and the first index value is less than the one at mid, the the minimum must be after the mid in the right half
                    lo = mid + 1;
                }
            }else{
                hi = mid;
            }
        }
        return nums[lo];
    }
}
```

The key issue with comparing with the first value (often referred to as "lo") is ambiguity in situations where the array might be rotated back to its original sorted order (or not rotated at all). In this case, it's hard to determine which direction to move in based on that comparison alone.  When comparing the "mid" value with the "hi" value, we have a clear direction:-

1. If "mid" is greater than "hi", the minimum value (or rotation start)
   is to the right of "mid".
2. If "mid" is less than or equal to "hi",
   the minimum value (or rotation start) is at "mid" or to the left of
   it.

So in this sense, the "hi" comparison more straightforward and effective for this specific problem.